# Как сделать содержимое модального окна разным для разных блоков

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Помогите с вопросом. В цикле карточки и модальное окно наполняются информацией. Но при клике по любой карточке открывается модальное окно с информацией только о первой карточке, хотя в инспекторе информация для каждой карточки своя. Как сделать так, чтоб показывалось модальное окно для конкретной карточки?

```
@model Checkitlink.Models.ViewModels.ProfileVM

@foreach (var item in Model.LinkListUserProfile)
{
***Карточка***
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 link-item linkCard">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="imgCardLink" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showLink" title="Подробнее..." src="http://checkitlink.com/img/screen/3596.jpeg">
            <div class="caption">
                <h5 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showLink">
                    @if (@item.LinkName.Length > 55)
                    {
                        <span title="@item.LinkName">
                            @item.LinkName.Substring(0, 55).Insert(55, "...")
                        </span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span title="@item.LinkName">
                            @item.LinkName
                        </span>
                    }
                </h5>
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <div class="btn-group link-actions" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link-favourite">  <span class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link-private"><span class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link-share"><span class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link-edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link-remove"><span class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group social-buttons" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"><span class="badge">42</span></span></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

***Начинается модальное окно***

    <div class="modal" id="showLink" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                        <a href="@item.LinkAddress" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank">
                            @item.LinkName
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body linkBodyModal col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                        <img class="linkImg" src="http://checkitlink.com/img/screen/3596.jpeg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <p>Автор: @item.UserAuthor</p>
                        <p>Категория: @item.LinkCategory</p>
                        <p>Дата: @item.CreatedAt</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body linkBodyModal col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    @if (item.LinkDescription == null)
                    {
                        <p></p>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>
                            @item.LinkDescription
                        </p>
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="@item.LinkAddress" target="_blank" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Перейти по ссылке</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем, кто ищет информацию по данному вопросу. Гениальное, как всегда, просто.

Чтоб не ковырятся с JS, в цикле каждому блоку присваиваем ID карточки data-target="#@item.LinkID" (в моем случае)

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 link-item linkCard">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="imgCardLink" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.LinkID" title="Подробнее..." src="http://checkitlink.com/img/screen/3596.jpeg">
            <div class="caption">
                <h5 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showLink">
```

И аналогично поступаем в модальном окне id="@item.LinkID"

```
<div class="modal" id="@item.LinkID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

Теперь у карточек разные ID и у каждого модального окна ID соответствующий карточке

Всем удачи!)